# Selenium : Switch to Alert not working after thread.sleep() for 2 seconds

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am clicking one button which results in an alert window. After that if i apply a wait of 2 seconds, and then try to click on "OK" button in the alert, it is not working & my selenium test keeps on waiting. No action is done & it does not even fail also.
If i remove Thread.sleep() in above step, it is working fine. Can anyone help me to understand why my test is not getting completed on applying thread.sleep().

Below is the code snippet:

driver.findElement(By.id("alertbtn")).click();

```
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Comment: Without seeing the page you are working on we can only guess

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.